# how to extract the last element in a String

Tags: java, android

I need to extract the amount in a string below, I need the string of "**1.50**",
eg.   CARD,S1234,1.50

I try to use `indexOf`, but then there might be few commas. If I use **.** for reference, the amount might be 100.50. Either way is not working.

Any idea?

Comment: does it has any pattern or not?

Comment: `String.split (",")` - get last element of the returned array

Comment: the example i gave is 3 elements, CARD, S1234,1.50  There might be more than 3, but amount will always at last.

Comment: @Scary Wombat  ok, i try that and see.

Comment: see my below answer for working code

Comment: When you have not working code, post a [mcve]. This is not a free code writing service where you just drop requirements and we do all the work.

Comment: say how your string pattern will be (is the amount always last string).

Comment: @jagapathi actually the title already mention it. Then in the comment, i need to repeat it once.

Comment: i need to know weather you amount will always be at last or not  (is yes) this question is already answered

Comment: @jagapathi yes, i already vote up 2 answers below

Comment: i see... i forgot the last step. Thanks. Mark answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split (",")` - get last element of the returned array:

```
  String str = "CARD,S1234,1.50";
  String arr[] = str.split (",");
  System.out.println(arr[arr.length -1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.split()` method:

```
String[] arrayString = "CARD,S1234,1.50".split(",");

String lastString = arrayString[arrayString.length - 1];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "CARD,S1234,1.50";
String last = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",")+1, s.length);
```

Comment: Also prints `,1.50`